# PHP month before last

Tags: php, date

I have used `date('F', strtotime('last month'))` successfully to get the name of the previous month (currently December) but how to I get the month before last (currently November)?

Looking at https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php this doesn't appear to be a built-in feature.

Comment: then just change it to `-2 months`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, yeah that does appear to be the solution for this.

Comment: Your best solution will give wrong results on certain days. Reason: See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
date('F',strtotime("-2 Months"));
```

For more details, have a look here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

======== EDIT =======
As [@jspit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7271221/jspit) mentioned, in certain days this solution will not work. For example:

```
echo date('F',strtotime("-2 Months", strtotime("31 January 2010")));
```

Instead of returning November as expected, we will get December. It is due to how `strtotime` calculates relative time by a string.

In order to fix this, we need **the timestamp of first day of current month** as a reference. This will be achieved by:

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-01')));
```

So the correct solution will be:

```
date('F',strtotime("-2 Months", strtotime(date('Y-m-01'))));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect (RiggsFolly solution looks good too but this is neat, compact, readable).

Comment: Your solution will give wrong results on certain days.

Comment: PHP date code makes me want to cry. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime Class builtin to PHP like this

```
echo (new DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P2M'))->format('F');
```

> Documentation for [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and the [DateInterval Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
date('F',strtotime("first Day of -2 Months"));
```

Why is "-2 months" not enough?

That doesn't always give the right result. Example:

```
$ts = strtotime('2021-04-30');  //April 30
$ts2MonthBefore = strtotime('-2 Month',$ts);
var_dump(date('F',$ts2MonthBefore));  //string(5) "March"
```

The same goes for datetime. Returns a wrong result.

```
echo (new DateTime('2021-04-30'))->sub(new DateInterval('P2M'))->format('F');
//March
```

Use:

```
echo date_create('First Day of -2 Month')->format('F');
```